# reset password MVC core 2.1 template with identity scaffold cannot find _Layoutlogin .cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, scaffolding

I am getting an error with my asp.net core 2.1 MVC project template. It looks like _Layoutlogin .cshtml is not able find. File is there in the shared folder and the only thing is that in the error message before .chmtl there is space at the end.  This is happening after scaffolding idenitity

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: The layout view '~/Views/Shared/_Layoutlogin .cshtml' could not be located. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/Shared/_Layoutlogin .cshtml
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.GetLayoutPage(ViewContext context, string executingFilePath, string layoutPath)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a typo some place if you check `_Layoutlogin .cshtml`  there is a space in their so if in fact your file is `_Layoutlogin.cshtml` its not going to find it.